# dotimeout not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout

I am trying to use the dotimeout plugin to create a delay for the effect of showing a sub-nav when hovering over the top nav. The plug in seems to work well when the active class is added to the first `li` but when added to subsequent `li`'s, it stops showing the hidden `ul` for this above the active `li`.

Here's my script:

```
$(function(){

    $('ul.main-nav').each(function(){
        var nav = $(this);

        nav
        .mouseover(function(e){
            nav.doTimeout( 'main-nav', 500, over, e.target );
        }).mouseout(function(){
            nav.doTimeout( 'main-nav', 500, out );
        });

        function over( elem ) {
            var parent = $(elem).closest( 'li.main-nav' );

            out( parent );
            parent.children( 'a' ).addClass( 'hover' );
            parent.children( 'ul:hidden' ).slideDown( 'fast' );
        };

        function out( elem ) {
            var parents = elem
                ? $(elem).closest( 'li.main-nav' ).siblings()
                : nav.children();

            if ( nav.is( '.main-nav-horizontal' ) ) {
                parents = parents.not( '.active' );
            }

            parents.children( 'a' ).removeClass( 'hover' );
            parents.children( 'ul' ).hide();
        };
    });

});
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZRH7/)

I can see people are using this plugin so this issue seems like it should be easily solved but everything as far as I can see should work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your out function to this.

```
function out( elem ) {

  var parents;

  if (elem) {
    parents = $(elem).closest( 'li.main-nav' ).siblings();
  }
  else {
    parents = nav.children();
    showthisone = parents.filter( '.active' );
    parents = parents.not( '.active' );
  }

  parents.children( 'a' ).removeClass( 'hover' );
  parents.children( 'ul' ).hide();

  if (!elem) {
    showthisone.children( 'a' ).addClass('hover');
    showthisone.children( 'ul' ).show();
  }

};
```